# Separating real and imaginary components of rectangular coordinates - matlab

Tags: string, matlab, split

I have a rectangular Coordinate in Matlab that looks like the following:

0.0240 - 0.1680i

I'd like to split the double into it real and imaginary parts, those parts being 0.0240 and -0.1680 (Don't need the i here)

I've converted the double into a string using the following:

```
I=0.0240 - 0.1680*i
I_1=num2str(I)
```

Im not sure how to proceed here to get what i want. strsplit() just gives back the string in the form it already is. Id like to somehow split it to give me the two numbers separately. I'm not too experienced with data manipulation in Matlab so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num2str` converts number to string. It is not for separating real and imaginary parts.

You can use:

```
I=0.0240 - 0.1680*i;
real_part=real (I)
imaginary_part=imag(I)
```

Comment: This does exactly what is needed, I just wasn't properly using the built in functions. Thanks